# I shouted at my mother due to anger and I’m regretting the thing I did

Tags: islamic-scholar

Salam alikum , I’m not that good at English so pardon me.

I don’t have a good relationship with my mother.
I usually get yelled at every useless thing , I get scolded , I get to listen harsh words from my mother that breaks the soul and there was one time she said that adoption was better than having me.

I don’t keep those words on my mind that much but sometimes it truly gets me..

Today a fight happened , she basically told me those harsh words and other hurtful words and by that time I got tired and I started shouting..
I said what did I do and what I have done and why you are always like this etc.

After a while she threatened me saying that she will do dua on me or she will call the police cause I disrespected her.

And rn I’m crying at my room regretting the stuff I did.

I’m also dealing with major depression and it’s not helping me with the current situation at all.

I’m sorry I couldn’t explain well since English is not my mother language..

Thank you for your time and I hope you can help me on what should I do..

Comment: And what is your question? Please consider reading [ask].

Comment: Sorry , my question is what should i do.. I’m trying to ask my mother to forgive me but she doesn’t accepts. If I repent to allah for my mistakes but my mother didn’t accept will I still be forgiven?

Comment: Repent to allah and ask forgiveness to your mother. If you did ask your mother to forgive you sincerely and she doesn't accept your forgiveness, Then there is no sin upon you. Just be good to your mother and repent to allah. And don't be sad because everyone makes mistake. What matters is how you react after making the mistake @Randomperson

Comment: Did you do anything to your mom to make her angry  ?

Comment: I truly didn’t do nothing.. I wanted to take the food to my dad but my dad said no take it back home. I took it back I told my mom in a peaceful way and she started cussing as if it was my fault... I didn’t know my dad wanted me to come to his shop cause he never told me at all. He called my mom and said where I am and why I didn’t came..after the call she started shouting , she started cussing , she said word that left me confused on what I have done simple.

Comment: If it was my mistake I would’ve accepted the consequences and would’ve accept the shouts and the cuss I wouldn’t say nothing.. but being scolded every single day , cussing every single day is truly hard to be patient.. I tried my best to be patient but that day my emotions got the better of me and I couldn’t control my anger.. everytime when I’m trying to be away from her or try to keep distance from her so I can’t hear her shouts and scolds yet she tries to find something and put it against me..

Comment: It’s truly difficult to handle her insults and scolds.. I ask only one day of peace where I can come from work and peacefully rest without being targeted on something I didn’t do..

Comment: I’ve repented and I’ve asked my mother to forgive me.. but she doesn’t accepts it , I told I couldn’t control my anger and it was tiring to be a punching bag without any reasons.. I told her to atleast be gentle with me but she didn’t react and neither spoke to me

Comment: I am so sorry for what u're going through and certainly must be hard. I guess you do have to have urself a little bit of credit given u remained patient, but as expected ure emotions got the better of you. As David said above, just repent to Allah, be sincere in you asking for your mother's forgiveness. If nothing else works, then there's no blame upon you. Just try to remain patient and polite the next time she confronts you for something you didn't do. Know that this is Allah's test upon you so be patient. I wanna ask though, have you reached out to your father? See if he is on your side?

Answer (score 2):

Salam random person,

I understand that sometimes parents could be tough. But it's important to remain patient. I see that your mother is angry at you and yells at you for no literal reason. If that's true, I advise to let her anger play out. Anger is like a drug and it's almost like someone being drunk. So let her get sober and stay patient until she calms down. I advise you to understand her perspective what is she going through? How would you have reacted if you were in her shoes? Ask these question, are you the problem or is it something else. If it's something else, talk to her in a noble fashion, have leniency in your heart just like how our prophet and Quran recommended. Talk to understand her situation and try to do something about it. I see that you have mentioned she said "adoption was better than having me", trust me no parent can ever give up on her child unless he's truly beyond saving. But who would know that other than Allah? Your mother loves you and it's just gonna be late until you realize it, unless you see the world through her glasses. Be grateful, that you have a mother, verily she's the easiest way to paradise so treat her like your queen. Most people can only dream of having a conversation with their mother whether it is for better or for worse.

Although, if it's you who is in error, then I immediately suggest you repent to Allah and your mother. Verily, if you lose her you lose Allah.